# 2D array to Dict

Tags: python, list

So my data looks like this

```
keys = ["Name", "Price", "Colour"]
fruits = ["Apple", "Pear", "Peach", "Banana"]
prices = [0.35, 0.40, 0.40, 0.28]
colour = ["Red", "Green", "Orange", "Yellow"]
```

and the result I need looks like this

```
expected = [
    {
        "Name": "Apple",
        "Price": 0.35,
        "colour": "Red"
    },
# ... ect 
]
```

I have one version of it like this

```
a = list(zip(fruits, prices, colour))
c = []
for value_set in a:
    b = {}
    for i, value in enumerate(value_set):
            b[keys[i]] = value
    c.append(b)
```

Is this the best solution or its this  bad practice ?

Comment: This solution is fine. Why would you think otherwise? Note, using `list` in `a = list(zip(fruits, prices, colour))` is unnecessary (and less efficient). Just remove `list`.

Comment: Also, I'd just use `for key, value in zip(keys, value_set): ...` instead of `enumerate(value_set)`

Comment: You can try: `[dict(zip(keys, vals)) for vals in zip(fruits, prices, colour)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the same `zip` technique that grouped up the dict values, to line those values up with the keys. A `dict` can be constructed directly from key-value pairs, and a list comprehension is a more elegant way to apply the process to each group of values.

So, I would write:

```
groups = zip(fruits, prices, colour)
expected = [dict(zip(keys, group)) for group in groups]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Pandas-module` can solve that point in just one step.

```
import pandas as pd

keys = ["Name", "Price", "Colour"]
fruits = ["Apple", "Pear", "Peach", "Banana"]
prices = [0.35, 0.40, 0.40, 0.28]
colour = ["Red", "Green", "Orange", "Yellow"]

df = pd.DataFrame([fruits, prices, colour], keys)
print([dict(df[i]) for i in range(3)])
```

Comment: Yep, with a suite of tools to further handle the data.